# automating CentOS 7 configuration using shell scripts

Tags: shell, shell-script, centos, yum, configuration

I notice I spend a lot of time using tutorials to manually configure a CentOS 7 server.  **How can I convert the manual steps from a tutorial into an automated shell script that can be used to configure multiple CentOS 7 servers with the same settings?**

Let's use [this tutorial](https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-install-nodejs-bower-and-gulp-on-a-centos-7-vps/) as an example, but the answer should be generalizable to other config shell scripts in addition to simply providing a working shell script to automate [this tutorial.](https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-install-nodejs-bower-and-gulp-on-a-centos-7-vps/)

Here is my first attempt at the shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
yum update
yum install yum-utils bzip2 bzip2-devel wget curl tar
sudo yum install gcc-c++
cd /opt
wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.7/node-v0.12.7.tar.gz
tar zxf node-v0.12.7.tar.gz
cd node-v0.12.7
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
make install  
npm install bower -g  
npm install gulp -g
```

How do I correctly write the shell script above?  And how do I check for example that each step is done correctly?  I have to be root to run the above.  If I run it as a sudoer, how do I handle the periodic requests for passwords?  Or does the fact that it is in a shell script mean that you only have to give the sudoer password when you first call the script?

I am brand new to shell scripts, so please be patient and explain in language that others who are new to shell scripting can also understand.

Also, not this is specific to CentOS 7 with things like `yum install`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several pieces to your question, and I can't claim familiarity with all of the commands you run, but here's my take:

Either run the whole script as root (directly) or via sudo. That way, you won't need to run sudo in the script itself. If you require sudo for a particular step, then you'll either need to set your ID up with a NOPASSWD flag in sudoers or accept an interactive prompt for your password during the script's execution.

To answer your other general question about each step executing correctly, the way to do that is to check the return code from the step and hope that the exiting program set the return code appropriately.

For examples:

> Short-hand notation:

```
yum update && \
yum install yum-utils bzip2 bzip2-devel wget curl tar
```

> Longer-hand:

```
yum update
RC=$?
if [ $RC -ne 0 ]
then
  print "Some error message here"
  exit 1 ## or some other identifying error code
fi

yum install yum-utils bzip2 bzip2-devel wget curl tar
RC=$?
if [ $RC -ne 0 ]
then
  print "Some other error message here"
  exit 2 ## or some other identifying error code
fi
...
```

Comment: Regarding the "hope the exiting program set the return code correctly" piece, my suggestion would be to add `echo $?` statements after each step of your current script and compare the printed return code with the actual result of the item above it. Ensure that a successful command returns zero and an unsuccessful one returns non-zero (as well-behaved programs/scripts should).

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned that it should be an automated shell script, at least for the two yum commands you would need to add `-y` so yum will assume an answer of "*yes*" for all questions it will ask.

See the [yum man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/yum), relevant excerpt:

> ```
>    -y, --assumeyes
>           Assume yes; assume that the answer to any question which would be asked is yes.
>           Configuration Option: assumeyes
> ```

For more detailed information on that, including some important hints to pay attention to, see the existing question: [Is "yum -y install" safe?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207395/is-yum-y-install-safe)