# Can I automatically accept MS SQL license terms while installing the yum package?

Tags: centos, yum, ansible

I am using **Ansible** to provision **MS SQL Server 2017** to a **CentOS 7.4** box. I first went through [this guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-red-hat) via command line and it works, but my end goal is to "Ansible-ize" it. However, when I get to the step about installing the command line tools, the `-y` switch does not work for accepting the license.

```
[user@host ~]$ sudo yum install -y mssql-tools unixODBC-devel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mssql-tools.x86_64 0:14.0.6.0-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: msodbcsql < 13.2.0.0 for package: mssql-tools-14.0.6.0-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: msodbcsql >= 13.1.0.0 for package: mssql-tools-14.0.6.0-1.x86_64
---> Package unixODBC-devel.x86_64 0:2.3.1-11.el7 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package msodbcsql.x86_64 0:13.1.9.1-1 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package          Arch     Version          Repository                     Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 mssql-tools      x86_64   14.0.6.0-1       packages-microsoft-com-prod   249 k
 unixODBC-devel   x86_64   2.3.1-11.el7     pwbank_repo                    55 k
Installing for dependencies:
 msodbcsql        x86_64   13.1.9.1-1       packages-microsoft-com-prod   4.0 M

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install  2 Packages (+1 Dependent package)

Total size: 4.2 M
Installed size: 4.4 M
Downloading packages:
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
Warning: RPMDB altered outside of yum.
The license terms for this product can be downloaded from
https://aka.ms/odbc131eula and found in
/usr/share/doc/msodbcsql/LICENSE.TXT . By entering 'YES',
you indicate that you accept the license terms.

Do you accept the license terms? (Enter YES or NO)
YES
  Installing : msodbcsql-13.1.9.1-1.x86_64                                  1/3 
The license terms for this product can be downloaded from
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=746949 and found in
/usr/share/doc/mssql-tools/LICENSE.txt . By entering 'YES',
you indicate that you accept the license terms.

Do you accept the license terms? (Enter YES or NO)
YES
  Installing : mssql-tools-14.0.6.0-1.x86_64                                2/3 
  Installing : unixODBC-devel-2.3.1-11.el7.x86_64                           3/3 
  Verifying  : msodbcsql-13.1.9.1-1.x86_64                                  1/3 
  Verifying  : unixODBC-devel-2.3.1-11.el7.x86_64                           2/3 
  Verifying  : mssql-tools-14.0.6.0-1.x86_64                                3/3 

Installed:
  mssql-tools.x86_64 0:14.0.6.0-1      unixODBC-devel.x86_64 0:2.3.1-11.el7     

Dependency Installed:
  msodbcsql.x86_64 0:13.1.9.1-1                                                 

Complete!
```

I noticed that there is a warning before I am prompted saying *RPMDB altered outside of yum.* Does this mean that Microsoft has specifically modified this rpm in their own way and, because of this, yum doesn't know how to handle it?

## My Goal

Although the above works for a "by hand" install, I am trying to "ansible-ize" the above. My playbook works up until I get to this play:

```
- name: Upgrade all installed packages, and install new ones
  package:
    name: '{{item}}'
    state: latest
  with_items:
    - '*'
    - mssql-server
    - mssql-tools
    - unixODBC-devel
```

The above play will update all of my currently installed packages and install **MS SQL Server 2017** just fine, but it will hang while trying to install the **mssql-tools** package, I assume because it is waiting for the user to accept the license.

## My Question

How can I "ansible-ize" this install if my playbook hangs, waiting for the user to accept the license?

For bonus points, there's a step where I have to run `sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup` and follow the on screen prompts which, again, impedes my provisioning. I am in the process of going through it once, finding its output file and seeing if I can't just copy that in whenever I re-provision a new box. Alternatively, I am in the process of reading up on [Expect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect).

Comment: Some old versions of MSODBC had a command line switch: `./install.sh install --accept-license`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
- name: install mssql-server repo (CentOS, RedHat)
  get_url:
    url: "{{ centos_repo_url }}"
    dest: /etc/yum.repos.d/mssql-server.repo
  when: ansible_distribution in ['CentOS', 'RedHat']

- name: install mssql-server repo (Ubuntu)
  get_url:
    url: "{{ ubuntu_repo_url }}"
    dest: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-server.list
  when: ansible_distribution == 'Ubuntu'

- name: refresh apt-get cache for server repo (Ubuntu)
  command: apt-get update
  when: ansible_distribution == 'Ubuntu'

- name: install mssql-server package
  package:
    name: mssql-server
    state: latest

- name: install mssql-tools package
  package:
    name: mssql-tools
    state: latest
  environment:
    ACCEPT_EULA: 'y'
```

A sample playbook for installing and configuring SQL Server (along with creating a Pacemaker-managed Availability Group) is available at https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/tree/master/samples/features/high%20availability/Linux/Ansible%20Playbook

Comment: Thank you, this fixed it. It was specifically the `environment: ACCEPT_EULA: 'y'` that I was missing.

Comment: FYI, a sample playbook for installing and configuring SQL Server is now available at https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/tree/master/samples/features/high%20availability/Linux/Ansible%20Playbook

Answer (score 10):

This should work in terms of EULA for Tools

`sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-tools unixodbc-dev`

As far as unattended install, you can specify environment variables or command line options for most things during setup. Take a look at [Sample: Unattended SQL Server installation script for Red Hat Enterprise Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sample-unattended-install-redhat).

**NOTE:** I noticed the repo in the links is still pointing to the older pre-RTM repo. Please use [these repos](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-change-repo) while we correct them.

Comment: I'm not using apt-get, I'm using yum. I'll try this in a bit here and let you know what I find. Thank you!

Comment: I just checked this way with `yum` and it works perfectly fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using rpm -ivh and want to run the setup non-interactively. Follow the steps mentioned.

Tested on Ubuntu and redat/ubi8-init

- export ACCEPT_EULA='y'
- rpm -ivh <package_name>

If you are trying to achieve the same in Dockerfile use the following:

RUN export ACCEPT_EULA='y' && rpm -ivh msodbcsql****.rpm

**Note**: Make sure export and rpm command is issues against a single RUN.